# Updating database after reordering Datatable

Tags: python, flask, datatables

I'm struggling with the datatables reordering. I want when user reorder to update table in the database. For this to happen i need:

1. to configure the datatable to send request to the server.
2. send the information about reordered datatable to flask endpoint.
3. Process data on the backend and update database table.

I have read the documentation but it is not clear to me.

My code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var dt = $('#data').DataTable({
    rowReorder: true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip'
    });       
});
```

Comment: The base DataTables library is a tool to **visualize** data, not to interact with a backend and modify data on a remote database.

To do that, you have to write all the needed code on your own, or purchase the **DataTables Editor** package, that has extensive libraries and API for backend languages like PHP, Nodejs and .NET (don't konw about Python) https://editor.datatables.net/

Comment: I've read the manual. Creating event on row reorder makes it possible.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

JavaScript code:

```
dt.on('row-reorder.dt', function (e, details, edit) {

      var  slownik  = {};
      for (var i = 0, ien = details.length; i < ien; i++) {
        
        let id_asortymentu = details[i].node.id;
        let nowa_pozycja = details[i].newPosition+1;
        console.log(id_asortymentu);
        console.log(nowa_pozycja);
        slownik[id_asortymentu] = nowa_pozycja;
      }
      req = $.ajax({
        url: 'asortymenty/tabela_reorder',
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data : JSON.stringify(slownik)
      });

      req.done(function(data){
          if (data.result == 1){
          console.log('Table reordered.');
        }
      });
    });
```

Flask backend code:

```
@admin.route('asortymenty/tabela_reorder', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def table_reorder():
    slownik=request.get_json('data')
    for key, value in slownik.items():
        asort = Asortyment.query.get(key)
        print(asort.pozycja)
        asort.pozycja = value
        db.session.add(asort)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'result' : '1'})
```